# AngularJS obtain rest xml data

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-rest

I have a class above, this method returns an xml result.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class RateController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/currencies/{ids}")
    public Currency getRates(@PathVariable String ids) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Currency.class);
//...
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(currency, System.out);
        return currency;
    }
}
```

Then i try to take it from angularjs, but i couldn't take the data. How can i obtain the data in xml formate in angularJS? That method is above.

```
var CurrencyController = function($http, $scope, $routeParams, exampleSvc) {
    var getCurrencies = function(data) {
        var result = $http.get("/api/currencies/" + $scope.ids);
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var json = x2js.xml_str2json(result);
        onCurrencyComplete(json);
    };
    var onCurrencyComplete = function(response) {
        $scope.currencies = response.data;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do like below in getCurrecies:

```
var getCurrencies = function(data) {
        $http.get("/api/currencies/" + $scope.ids).then(function(response){
             var result = response.data
             var x2js = new X2JS();
             var json = x2js.xml_str2json(result);
             onCurrencyComplete(json);
        });
};
```

Comment: i did but still same with previous one.